# MLE for shifted distribution

Tags: self-learning, maximum-likelihood

A random variable X has the following pdf:

$ f(x|\theta_{1},\theta_{2})=\theta_{1}  \left(x-\theta_{2} \right){}^{\theta_{1} -1}e^{-\left(x-\theta_{2} \right){}^{\theta_{1} }}$

(a) Based on an i.i.d. random sample (sample size n = 11):
$X = [11.359 , 10.173 , 10.209 , 10.850 , 10.472 , 11.397 , 10.929 , 10.297  10.483 , 10.203 , 11.023]$, find the MLE of $[\theta_{1},\theta_{2}]$  (optimality check is required).

I tried to find the log-likelihood but I get stuck since when I take the derivative with respect to $\theta_1$ I can't get rid of the $\theta_2$ .. any suggestions or hints ?

Thanks

Comment: What is the domain of $x$ (and the parameters) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Derivative wrt $\theta_1$ will result in an equation with $\theta_2$ and vice versa. There **maynot** exist a closed form solution and you may have to resort to **Fisher-Scoring** or **Newton-Raphson** methods to getan answer!

Comment: Can it be solved using Mathematica or Matlab software ? .. I've never heard about these methods before .. I'll google them

Comment: @Bassem These are basically iterative methods that you need to execute.